# show/hide div based on the input of textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page which has a text box asking the user how many no of categories
they want to add like this:

```
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group">
    <label>How many SubCategories? *</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control" id="SelName">
</div>
```

Using jQuery or JavaScript, I want to show/hide these div elements based on the input of the user; If "1" show div 1 only, if "2" show div 1 and 2 together, if "3" show 1,2,3 together and so on.

```
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group" id="image1">
    <label>SubCategory Name 1:*</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group" id="image2">
    <label>SubCategory Name 2:*</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group" id="image3">
    <label>SubCategory Name 3:*</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: You can create hide/show (for example display:none) classes and then go through a loop and set these classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Add a common class for all the `div`s group them all together, let's name it `myDivs`.
2. Listen for `input` event on the input with id `SelName`.
3. Use `show` and `hide` functions in `JQuery` to control the visibility according to the input value (all hidden by default).
4. If the input value is set, iterate over the `div`s and show the ones that their `index+1` is less or equal than the input value.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
     hideAll();
     $('#SelName').on('input', function(){
          let num = $(this).val();
          let divs = $('.myDivs');
          hideAll();
          if(num){
               for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
                    let div = divs[i];
                    if(i+1 <= num)
                         $(div).show();
               }
          }
     });
     function hideAll(){
          let divs = $('.myDivs');
          for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
               let div = divs[i];
               $(div).hide();
          }
     }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group">
     <label>How many SubCategories? *</label>
     <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control" id="SelName">
</div>

<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group myDivs" id="image1">
     <label>SubCategory Name 1:*</label>
     <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group myDivs" id="image2">
     <label>SubCategory Name 2:*</label>
     <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group myDivs" id="image3">
     <label>SubCategory Name 3:*</label>
     <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it with show/hide you only have limited numbers. You can instead create a loop and create as much inputs as user needs. Look at my example below:

```js
$(".form-control").on("change", function(){
var inputVal = $(".form-control").val();
$(".sub-cats").html("");
for (i = 1; i <= inputVal; i++){
 $(".sub-cats").append('<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group" id="image' + i +'"><label>SubCategory Name '+i+':*</label><input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control"></div>');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group">
  <label>How many SubCategories? *</label>
  <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control" id="SelName">
</div>
<div class="sub-cats">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add a class name to all subcategories, e.g. `subcategory`, and set all subcategories to `display:none;` Then you could do the following:

```js
$("#SelName").on("change", function() {
  let count = $(this).val();
  let subcategories = $(".subcategory");
  for (let i = 0; i <= subcategories.length; i++) {
    if (i + 1 <= count) {
      $(".subcategory:eq(" + i + ")").show();
    } else {
      $(".subcategory:eq(" + i + ")").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.subcategory {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group">
  <label>How many SubCategories? *</label>
  <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control" id="SelName">
</div>
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group subcategory" id="image1">
  <label>SubCategory Name 1:*</label>
  <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group subcategory" id="image2">
  <label>SubCategory Name 2:*</label>
  <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-12-xxxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group subcategory" id="image3">
  <label>SubCategory Name 3:*</label>
  <input type="number" placeholder="#" class="form-control">
</div>
```